# How to export an SAPUI5 application to PhoneGAP and then generate the . APK

Tags: android, eclipse, phonegap-build, sapui5

Hi  at this point i have created my SAPUI5 app in eclipse i found many tutorials but no one can explain exactly or in a structured maner, how  export  my eclipse sapui5 project to phonegap pattern  and then  create the .apk (at this point i think if i have the phonegap pattern OK, just upload to Adobe Phone Gap Build and generate the .apk). Anyone could help me in this case?

Thank you all.

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but you can just use the openUI5 files. Extract the files, point your bootstrap to the local sap-ui-core.js and then just build the apk. (I use cordova, so it's just the "cordova build" command).

Comment: When you say "point the bootstrap" , you mean like this "<script src="resources/sap-ui-core.js>"

Comment: Exactly. If you extracted the OpenUI5 files so that resources/sap-ui-core.js exists it should work.

Comment: And what is this "cordova build" command, you have an example how i execute this to generate the .apk,

Comment: Phonegap is based on cordova, so the commands should work. In the project folder I execute "cordova build" or "cordova build --release"  afterwards the apks are in the platform folder - for you it should be just as easy replacing the "cordova" with "phonegap"

Comment: But my project it's not a Cordova project so when i try to cordova build i receuve a message "not a cordova-based project"

Comment: Did you type "phonegap build android"?

Comment: Yes, see  E:\SAP_WORKSPACE\MobilePRU>phonegap build android
[phonegap] executing 'cordova build android'...
Current working directory is not a Cordova-based project.

Comment: Is it the directory with the config.xml in it?

Comment: no because this project was created in eclipse as SAPUI5 Project